# JSF Primefaces - Picklist: Determine first entry in both tables

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to determine the first entry in a picklist?
I need it because tooltip doesn't work for picklist and I need to place the first tooltip under the first entry

Comment: You can use DualListModel to prepare content of picklist. Then it is up to you how records will be sorted in source section of picklist and which one is first. For target section it may be tricky. But for tooltip you can add (info) icon beside picklist and attach tooltip there. Or wrap picklist with panel and do tooltip related functionality there. Another way is add column(s) inside picklist and try to use header for tooltip purpose.